# How to import JavaScript file into angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I am having trouble figuring out how to import a javascript file into my angular2 project. It is a file that is not a module that is apart of npm and the only instructions I have been able to find is using npm which is not an option here.

I am using angular cli and in my angular-cli.json file I have:

```
{
"apps": [
  "styles": [..],
  "scripts": ["../pathtomyjs/file.js"] 
]}
```

I ran ng build and ng serve and when I open up my app and look at the web console and try referencing the function that is in my js file, I am able to do so successfully.

Example in the console I type in:

```
var test = MyObject;
```

and I get test = {};

However, when I try do

```
let test = MyObject;
```

in my component .ts file I get :

```
home.component.ts (10,11): Cannot find name 'MyObject'.)
```

Not sure how to do this in Angular2.

Thanks!

Comment: i did a deep dive on this here: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45549698/how-to-include-3rd-party-library-that-uses-older-import-approach-to-angular4-x/45557326#45557326)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do:

```
declare var MyObject: any;

let test = MyObject;
```

Or:

```
let test = (<any> MyObject);
```

For jQuery:

```
declare var jQuery: any;

jQuery.ajax({ ... });
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, I ended putting the declare var statement below the import statements in my ts file and I tried doing let test = MyObject but I was still getting an error. Changing let to public worked though! Was there something I did wrong that made declaring as "let" not work?

Comment: Nevermind, I just needed to drop the "let" in front of test and I no longer needed "public".

Answer (score 2):

Is it a 3rd party library? you'll have to let the typescript compiler know where the type definition files are.  Normally, it looks under `node_modules/@types` folder.  For example, if you wanted to use `jQuery`, you would install the necessary type definition files by running:

```
npm install @types/jquery
```

Answer (score 1):

I did a deep dive on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45549698/how-to-include-3rd-party-library-that-uses-older-import-approach-to-angular4-x/45557326#45557326):

This is a great question and I'm glad you ask because I wish I had what I'm about to write the first time I encountered this little problem.  This is a typescript/javascript and webpack issue before it is an angular issue.  I definitely am planning a writeup on [my blog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45549698/how-to-include-3rd-party-library-that-uses-older-import-approach-to-angular4-x/45557326#45557326) soon as possible.

### Your Scenario:

You run

```
npm install mathjs
```

1. Now you try to use math.js from a component:
2. Find math.js dist js file (node_modules/mathjs/dist/math.js) and reference like this

   `import {mathjs} from "../../node_modules/mathjs/dist/math";`
3. But you get error message saying `"set --allowJS".`  You do that like this:

   `Set --allowJS in config (tsconfig.json) 
   {    "compilerOptions": {
       "allowJs": true, ...`
4. Now you get:

> ERROR in ../node_modules/mathjs/dist/math.js (12209,13): Unreachable
>   code detected.

5. Looking in the math.js source, you see that it is an old school module but there is no root wrapper function (one function to bring them all and in the darkness bind them..) (more on that later).

***Solution*: install a typings file for the target lib (@types/mathjs)**

[read more...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45549698/how-to-include-3rd-party-library-that-uses-older-import-approach-to-angular4-x/45557326#45557326)

Answer (score 0):

I put my `js` files into `app/assets/scripts` and load them in `index.html` 
`<script src="assets/scripts/foobar.js"></script>` . This is for a `ionic2` / `angular2` project.

In the module you have to define your functions like this in global scope of the module file

`declare var myFancyFunction;`