# Importing style sheets in angular4

Tags: css, angular

Am trying upgrade my project from angular JS to angular 4. I have style sheets which i have used in angular JS project.

This is my folder structure

[image]

I created components using angular CLI. 
Everything works perfect but i don't know how to use my styles in angular 4 project.
Can some one explain how i can use my styles globally? and also only in certain components?

Answer (score 14):

You can add your styles within the  `angular-cli.json`:

```
"styles": [
  // Your styles go here
]
```

This is for global styles. Local styles (for a certain component) are within the accordant CSS-file, which belongs to your component, e.g. *foo.component.css*. By default each component has the following annotation:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-foo',
  templateUrl: './foo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./foo.component.css'],
})
```

So, *foo.component.css* contains the CSS for the component `FooComponent`.

Take a look here:

- [Component Styles](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles)
- [Global styles](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-styles)

Comment: How can I add `.js` file for certain `components`?

Comment: Take a look e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42478930/how-to-import-javascript-file-into-angular2) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44817349/how-to-include-external-js-file-in-angular-4-and-call-function-from-angular-to-j).

Comment: I know that I need import my `.js` files in `.angular-cli.json > scripts: [ ... ]`, but I want use my `.js` scripts only in one component...

Comment: Maybe you can ask a new question here on SO. There you can add your accordant code and so on. This might be better than using comments.

Comment: Yes You are right. but I think You know  the answer... )

Comment: If you want to use a library from the directory _node_modules_, which you have installed via npm (maybe with the accordant _@types_-package), you should be able to do something like `import {Router} from 'express';` in your component. You do not need to use the `scripts`-array then.

Comment: Thanks, just now I trying to post new question about that... ) see You there...)

Answer (score 6):

Apart from adding the css file to angular-cli.json as shown by @pzaenger you can also add it to index.html page of your app as shown below :-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

OR

you can even import it into an existing CSS file in your app by adding the @import statement at the top of that file as shown below :-

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

**This way you can also add CDN links of the CSS file which cannot be done in angular-cli.json file.** You can find a more elaborated explanation at this [link](http://getgoingit.blogspot.in/2018/02/adding-bootstrap-style-sheets-to.html).