# Angular Project hosting after open sans font css Node Module not working

Tags: angular, node-modules

I added my angular project for open sans and i added this   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/open-sans-fontface/open-sans.css">` in `header`,

when i run the project on  localhost , that node_module working fine. but i hosted my project , that    `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/open-sans-fontface/open-sans.css">` not working . anyone know how to fix that issue .

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46363468/importing-style-sheets-in-angular4

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `<link>` tag, you can import your styles in `angular.json`

`"styles": [
  "./node_modules/open-sans-fontface/open-sans.css"
]`

all these style files will be affected globally.